# C int to char array on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, printf, itoa

I'm trying to convert an `int` to a `char*`. I'm on a Mac OS X so I can't use `itoa`, since it's non-standard, I'm trying to use `sprintf` or `snprintf` but I keep on getting `segmentation fault: 11`. 
Here's what I've got:

```
snprintf(msg, sizeof(char *), "%d", 1);
```

So I'm hoping for a suggestion, what can I do?

Comment: I'm guessing that `msg` is a `char *` that hasn't had any memory allocated to it, yes?

Comment: yes it's a char* variable

Comment: Then I'm guessing that you haven't allocated any memory to it. Lemme write an answer out.

Comment: yeah, that was it, sorry for such a simple mistake... I didn't thought that it had to be allocated first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that `msg`, which is a `char *`, doesn't point to memory that it can use. So you first have to dynamically allocate memory that will be used to store the string.

```
msg = malloc(12); // 12 is an arbitrary value
snprintf(msg, 12, "%d", 1); // second parametre is max size of string made by function
```

Alternatively, you can instead declare a static buffer. That way, you won't have to free any memory.

```
char msg[12]; // again, 12 is an arbitrary value
snprintf(msg, sizeof(msg), "%d", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you declare msg?

Something like this should work:

```
char msg[15];
snprintf(msg, sizeof(msg), "%d", 1);
```

Note that the second argument to `snprintf` is the length of the string, not the size of a character.